# GridLengthAnimation WinRT

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

Is there a way to make a GridLength animation (on a RowDefinition.Heigt) in WinRT ?

Thanks in advance,
NeoKript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No and you probably shouldn't animate a row's size since it's a dependent animation. If you really need to do it though - set the `RowDefinition.Height` to `Auto` and animate the `Height` of the content within that row.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely agree with the above assertion on how you should animate the row size, there's several occasions where you might want to collapse a row / column completely (i.e snapped view).

You can easily animate the Height / Width using the following storyboard.

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="100" x:Name="LeftSpacerColumn" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" x:Name="QuoteColumn" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="75" x:Name="MiddleSpacerColumn" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="450" x:Name="ButtonSpacerColumn" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="100" x:Name="RightSpacerColumn"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


<Storyboard>
    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Width)" Storyboard.TargetName="LeftSpacerColumn">
       <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                <GridLength>0</GridLength>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to actually animate. It just jumps instantly to the new Width.